# C++ how can i get the name in class to make it as a ranking system based on the time I input

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures

Can I store my object in a class in a variable so that I can print the ranking name?

The question is to write a program that asks for the names of five runners and the time it took each of them to finish a race. The program should display who came in first, second, and third place. Only accept positive numbers for the times.

Any modification that I should make?

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class runner{
    public:
        char name[50];
        float time;
        
        void input(){
            
            cout <<"\n Enter the name: ";
            cin>> name;
            cout <<"\n Enter the time taken to finish the race (mins): ";
            cin>> time;
        }
        
        
        
};

int main(){
    
    runner runners[5];
    for(int i =0;i<5; i++){
        
        runners[i].input();
    }
    
    int i,first, second, third, fourth, fifth;
    fifth = fourth = third = first = second = INT_MIN;
    char firstname, secondname, thirdname, fourthname, fifthname;
    for(int i =0;i<5; i++){
        if(runners[i].time>first){
            fifth = fourth; 
            fourth = third; 
            third = second; 
            second = first; 
            first = runners[i].time;    
            
        }
        else if(runners[i].time> second){
            fifth = fourth; 
            fourth = third; 
            third = second; 
            second = runners[i].time; 
        }
        else if(runners[i].time>third){
            fifth = fourth; 
            fourth = third; 
            third = runners[i].time; 
            
        }
        else if(runners[i].time>fourth){
            fifth = fourth; 
            fourth = runners[i].time; 
            
        }
        else if(runners[i].time>fifth){
            fifth = runners[i].time; 
        
        }
    }

    
    cout << first <<","<< second <<","<< third <<","<< fourth<< ","<< fifth<<endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You just need to overload the `<` operator.

Comment: I recommend you learn about [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) Passing a custom ordering function you can order (sort) the array `runners` to have the "winner" in the first element and the "looser" in the last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simplify your program by using `std::multiset` as shown [below](https://onlinegdb.com/BRSWunvqE):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set> 

//using namespace std; //don't use this

class runner{
    public:
        std::string name; //use string instead of array of char
        float time;
        
        void input(){
            
            std::cout <<"\n Enter the name: ";
            std::cin>> name;
            std::cout <<"\n Enter the time taken to finish the race (mins): ";
            std::cin>> time;
        }
        //overload operator< since we are using std::set
        bool operator<( const runner &r ) const
        {
            return ( time < r.time );
        }
};

int main(){
    
    std::multiset<runner> runners; //use multiset instead of array
    for(int i =0;i<5; i++){
        
        runner tempRunner;
        tempRunner.input();
        
        runners.insert(tempRunner);
    }
    
    int i = 0;
    //print out the details as asked in the assignment question. You can adjust 
//the output according to your needs for example if you want to display only first 
//3 position details or what if all the first three persons in the multiset have the same timing
    for(const runner &tempRunner: runners)
    {
        std::cout<<tempRunner.name <<" came: "<<i+1<<std::endl;
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note `multiset` is used instead of `set` because more than one runner can have the same time.

Comment: The problem with this is that it doesn't allow two or more runners with the same time.

Comment: @Yup can just use `multiset` then as i have done in my edit. Now only the output needs to be adjusted for same time.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.

You can write a custom compare function:

```cpp
class runner
{
public:
    std::string name; // why not std::string?
    float time;
        
    void input()
    {    
        std::cout <<"\n Enter the name: ";
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout <<"\n Enter the time taken to finish the race (mins): ";
        std::cin >> time;
    }
};

bool cmp (const runner &lhs, const runner &rhs)
{
    return lhs.time < rhs.time;
}
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const runner& run)
{
    out << run.name << ' ' << run.time;
}
int main()
{
    runner runners[5];
    for(int i =0;i<5; i++)
    {
        runners[i].input();
    }
    std::sort(runners, runners + 5, cmp);

   for(int i {4}; i >= 0; --i)
   {
       std::cout << runners[i] << ' ' << i << ',';
   }
}
```

Or you can overload the `<` operator:

```cpp
class runner
{
public:
    std::string name; 
    float time;
        
    void input()
    {    
        std::cout <<"\n Enter the name: ";
        std::cin >> name;
        std::cout <<"\n Enter the time taken to finish the race (mins): ";
        std::cin >> time;
    }
};
bool operator< (const runner &lhs, const runner &rhs)
{
    return lhs.time < rhs.time;
}
int main()
{
    runner runners[5];
    for(int i =0;i<5; i++)
    {
        runners[i].input();
    }
    std::sort(runners, runners + 5);
    for(int i {4}; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        std::cout << runners[i] << ' ' << i << ',';
    }
}
```